# How to migrate part of an SVN repo with history to a new Git repository?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

I need to migrate part of an SVN repo to git.

For example, the SVN root is: `http://example.com/svn/project` and I need to migrate a project subdirectory like `http://example.com/svn/project/trunk/foo/bare`.

I tried to use:

```
git svn clone http://example.com/svn/project \
    -Ttrunk/foo/bare --no-metadata -A ~/authors-transform.txt ~/temp
```

After this command I get a git repo with two branches: `trunk` and `trunk@61`, but I need only one branch.

What do I need to do to get only one branch after migrating?

Comment: Maybe working on the svndump, removing unneeded branches, make a new svn repository, then convert it to git??

Comment: Good idea, but how can i manage dumped file? its look like binary

Comment: `svnadmin dump` produces a textual file, at least when the repository always contained textual files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the branch that you don't need, of course. But you'll loose the history before revision 61.

The `trunk@61` exists because the directory you are importing was replaced. In a way that git svn does not see as continuation of history. Therefore it recorded the value of the ref at that revision and started again.

Since it's a one-off conversion, you can use graft to connect the history, filter-branch to rewrite it, so the graft file is not needed (see filter-branch documentation) and than delete the now useless branch.